# Can ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Validation handle property bags?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, properties, asp.net-mvc-2-validation

I've been reading about ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Validation and I'm in love with the fact that it will automatically apply the same rules to your client side and server side objects.  However, all the examples I've seen have used custom model objects.  A design I'm working on uses property bags (a list of key->value pairs, like a dictionary) that can each have different validations.

For example

- Invoice Number: AlphaNumeric, Exactly 10 characters
- User Name: Less than 50 characters.
- Invoice Amount: Money.

Can ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Validation validate those rules, with or without a custom validation engine?

Answer (score 1):

> Can ASP.NET MVC 2 Model Validation
>   validate those rules, with or without
>   a custom validation engine?

Sorry about my last answer, it was a bit vague. For any lenght or character count validation regulars expressions are the key. However your situation is a bit different.

Here what can be done using mvc 2 model validation :

```
   1. using System;  
   2. using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;  
   3.   
   4. namespace FunWithMvc2RC2  
   5. {  
   6.     public class Test  
   7.     {  
   8.         // StringLenght  
   9.         [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 25 Characters")]  
  10.         public string StringLength { get; set; }  
  11.   
  12.         // Required  
  13.         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]  
  14.         public string Required { get; set; }  
  15.   
  16.         // Required and StringLenght  
  17.         [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required Field")]  
  18.         [StringLength(5, ErrorMessage = "Maximum 25 Characters")]  
  19.         public string Combos { get; set; }  
  20.   
  21.         // Range Attribute  
  22.         [Range(1, 31, ErrorMessage = "Minimum 1; Maximum 31")]  
  23.         public int Range { get; set; }  
  24.   
  25.         // RegularExpression Attribute  
  26.         [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-Za-z0-9]+_+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\-+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\.+)|([A-Za-z0-9]+\++))*[A-Za-z0-9]+@((\w+\-+)|(\w+\.))*\w{1,63}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]  
  27.         public string Regex { get; set; }  
  28.   
  29.         // Custom Regular Expression EmailAttribute  
  30.         [Email(ErrorMessage = "Email Validation")]  
  31.         public string Email { get; set; }  
  32.     }  
  33. }
```

So i would say that for custom stuff such using a list of key and all with those build-in validatioin, this isnt possible using default validation rules included in MVC 2. You will need to make your own validation rules. See custom model validation at http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx.

Hope that help.

Comment: I'm not sure how that answers the question.  Can you expand on that?